# WordPress how to add another tab with custom meta boxes on the admin post/edit side bar?

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes, wordpress-plugin-creation

Although, I've successfully added meta box to the admin side bar with following code,

```
function custom_register_meta_boxes()
{
    add_meta_box('custom-1', __('My custom meta box', 'custom'), 'custom_display_callback', 'post', "side", "high", null);
   
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'custom_register_meta_boxes');
```

I'd like to ask if a possibility to add another tab on the admin post/edit tab beside the "Block" tab. (see image).

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/tab-panel/#development-guidelines

Did you tried this ? Gutenberg is more JS based, it could be a good start.